# How can I use dynamic values in a language generation template?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I would like to re-use a given set of "language generation" sentences in bot composer, while filling it with localized values.

See my example execution + LG template, which does not work.

--> the target LG template

```
${defaultResponse("Yes")}
```

--> the source LG template

```
defaultResponse(defaultValue)
```

I did not understand your input, so I have made a decision for you and answered the question with `"${defaultValue}"`.

Any idea what I do wrong? I do not find something similar in the documentation.

Comment: Typically you create your different language in different LG files for each language. For example, you may have `# FoodChoices()
- ["Bread","Fruit", "Pizza"]` for English and `# FoodChoices()
- ["Obst", "Brot", "Pizza"]` for German. This is described more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, yes! That I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create bot with different languages, there is a function called Multilingual support. It's introduced in document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language

The structure looks like as below when you created bot with Chinese and English.

```
/coolbot
   coolbot.dialog
   /language-generation
      /en-us
         common.en-us.lg
         coolbot.en-us.lg
      /zh-cn
         common.zh-cn.lg
         coolbot.zh-cn.lg
   /language-understanding
      /en-us
         coolbot.en-us.lu
      /zh-cn
         coolbot.zh-cn.lu
```